# Validating form in mvc3 modal dialog window

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, kendo-ui

I am using mvc3 with the KendoUI window control to open up a partial view in a modal window.

I have a form with the popup that I am trying to validate before sending the form back to the server.

I have a click event on my main view that looks like

```
  $("#submit-campaign").live("click",function () {
    var form = $("#Send");
    $.validator.unobtrusive.parse($(form));
     form.validate();
    if (form.valid()) {
        console.log("valid");
    } else {
        console.log("invalid");
    }

});
```

However its always been returned as true even if I haven't added values to some of the required.

I have referenced the 3 javascript files like

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

What do I need to do so I am getting the actual validation state clientside from the popup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to check validation would be.

```
$("#submit-campaign").live("click",function () {
    var form = $("#Send");
    $.validator.unobtrusive.parse($(form));
    var val = form.validate();
    if (val.valid()) {
        console.log("valid");
    } else {
        console.log("invalid");
    }

});
```

Comment: Hi IUnkown. That still is always been returned as valid

Comment: Are you using RenderPartial inside your Telerik Window control? If not then you need to, since the scriptregistrar cannot figure it out for you otherwise.

Comment: I wasn't before now I am using   <div id="window">
            @Html.Action("CreateCampaign");
        </div> as I have some extra work I am doing in the action before its loaded

Comment: In that case are you also referencing the validation files in both your caller and callee windows?

Comment: Can you try the suggestions listed in this thread at [Telerik forums](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-mvc/window/validation-in-window-control-not-working.aspx)?